# Can't call some commands with the 'system' function in C++ on MacOS (they work in terminal by hand)

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, latex, system

I'm starting my adventure with LaTeX and I want a .tex file to be converted to .pdf by a C++ program. I can do it by hand by typing `pdflatex foo.tex` in Terminal and it gives me foo.pdf. So to the working directory of my program I copied the foo.tex file and I want to use the `system("pdflatex foo.tex")` function to convert it but the program gives me this error: `sh: pdflatex: command not found`. Using the `pwd` function gives me the correct directory containing the .tex file so it can't be not finding the file. Other simple commands like `mkdir` work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try with the full path to `pdflatex`

Comment: Thanks, I've not thought of `pdflatex` as of something that would have a path (stupid). It works.

Comment: Iirc it's only the shell searching the elements in the `PATH` environment variable for program names (at least on Windows and Linux, not familiar how exactly this works on macos, but probably some similar logic is used by the shell for locating the executable); the `system` function is not the shell.

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare and should never be used.

Comment: @fabian On Windows, [`system()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem) literally spawns a copy of the shell (usually `cmd`) and passes the command on to it, as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the shell which is spawned by `system()` uses a different PATH environment.   Although like @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz says, use the full path in the `system()` call, otherwise you will need to modify those default PATHs to include your tool’s location. Cf. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33246/311469